# Class not found exception in eclipse web project (applet)

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, applet

I'm trying to create web application in eclipse. [image: Please see my screenshot.] I want Eclipse to generate .class file that would be reffered from index.html. What should I do?

Comment: Can you further explain what you're wanting to do with the .class files?

Comment: I need .class file, because it is reffered from index.html

Comment: If you're just wanting to link to the .class file, then place the .class file in a public directory somewhere.  I'm likely misunderstanding the requirement stil.

Comment: The requirement is to make this applet work instead of getting classnotfound exception. How can I force eclipse to put .class files in a proper place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create new folder for applets: webProj->Properties->Java Build Path->Default Output folder
2. Update applet tag: applet code="SimpleApplet.class" codebase ="./applet/" width=400 height=200

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse compiles *.java files automatically. Ensure Project -> Build automatically is selected.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a bin or classes folder in the same path as your project that contains the .class files.

Comment: How can I force Eclipse to generate these files from .java files?

Comment: It generates them automatically, just look in the folder, not in eclipse.

Comment: You can see in screenshot that these files are not available to servlet, what should I do to fix that?